# Buffer size for File.OpenRead

Tags: c#, .net, io

If you use one of `FileStream` constructors you can specify buffer size in bytes but if you use `File.OpenRead` you can't. What is the default value for buffer size which is used in the secondcase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Telerik JustDecompile to look at the code, it's 4096 B:

```
public static FileStream OpenRead(string path)
{
    return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
}

public FileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) : this(path, mode, access, share, 4096, FileOptions.None, Path.GetFileName(path), false)
{
}
```

Comment: +1 for being a good sportsman friend. And a good way of getting the answer too. :D

Answer (score 5):

It's `4096` as you can see from this constructor:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public FileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
    : this(path, mode, access, share, 4096,
           FileOptions.None, Path.GetFileName(path), false)
{
}
```

That's the constructor called by `OpenRead`:

```
public static FileStream OpenRead(string path)
{
    return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
}
```

Comment: FYI: Note that 4K is the default cluster size used for NTFS disks up to 16TB in size, which may be why MS chose that as the default size for FileStream(). http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365

Comment: @MatthewWatson, yes I would agree with you on that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But @w128 answered earlier than you. Wish I could accept both answers

Comment: Actually, I think it's fair to point out that he seems to have answered a few moments earlier.

Comment: @w128, I see 2 minutes difference between your answers in your favor

Comment: 4K is too small to be used in Azure VMs, which typically can only do 100-500 IOs per second.